# How to escape HTML in HAML form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

When I do an edit, my HAML form renders with the `&ampersand;` value in the text field. I have set `escape_html` to true but still it renders the value with `&ampersand;` What mistake I have done here? Is this the right syntax?

My form:

```
= f.text_field :display_name, escape_html => true
```

Comment: A text field value shouldn't be escaped anyway--what does the DB value actually contain? Although for a hash key it should be a symbol.

Comment: In db all values contains &amp; symbol,instead of changing all the values in db,Can i do using html_safe or escape_html?

Comment: You could set the value manually, I guess. I'm not aware that there's something in the form tags that will unescape HTML, but I'm unaware of a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

To preface, I am just learning haml (as of a few hours ago) but I think I have at least a good place for you to start because I think your problem is you need to set it to `false`, not `true` or you should try to unescape the html.
I think your best bet is to look at this bit of haml's reference.

> "Rails XSS Protection
>
> Haml supports Rails’ XSS protection scheme, which was introduced in Rails 2.3.5+ and is enabled by default in 3.0.0+. If it’s enabled, Haml’s :escape_html option is set to true by default - like in ERB, all strings printed to a Haml template are escaped by default. Also like ERB, strings marked as HTML safe are not escaped. Haml also has its own syntax for printing a raw string to the template.
>
> If the :escape_html option is set to false when XSS protection is enabled, Haml doesn’t escape RUBY strings by default. However, if a string marked HTML-safe is passed to Haml’s escaping syntax, it won’t be escaped.
>
> Finally, all the Haml helpers that return strings that are known to be HTML safe are marked as such. In addition, string input is escaped unless it’s HTML safe."

from http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#rails_xss_protection

I'm not an expert but from what I can understand, if you set the `:escape_html` option to `true`, you will always get sanitized html back.  If you're using the most current version of haml, your default will be set to true.  Try setting it to `false`, instead.

Another useful thing I just found is to unescape html.  You can try to use != in front of the haml that contains the html you want to leave un-sanitized.  for example - `!= "I feel <strong>!"` compiles to a I feel !.

from http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html

I hope this helps and sorry if you already knew that stuff or if it wasn't answering what you were asking about.
Good Luck!

Answer (score -3):

I think Ruby has some function `.html_safe` or `raw()` so that when you save it will give you clean text.

Comment: This is not only wrong, it's dangerously so. Both of those methods assume that the input is safe and do nothing, and rendering data using either will leave you open to injection attacks like cross-site scripting.